# Knockoutjs-Creating dependent drop down list while updating record Zend

Tags: javascript, zend-framework, knockout.js

I am new to **knockoutjs** and creating a project. In this, I am updating a form where there is selecting state from which stateId will fetch city list, cityId fetches zipcodes and so on.
        For initial array, I have prefetch before calling Model, But while updating state, all the cities should be empty and refilled according to selected stateID and so on. **My SelectedCityAction is not updating while selecting state.** Can anyone help me out?

```
    EditUserAddressModel = function( statesJson, citiesJson , zipcodeJson, Addressdata)  {

        var self = this;
        self.selectedStateAction = ko.observable(Addressdata.state_id);
        self.selectedCityAction = ko.observable(Addressdata.city_id);
        self.selectedZipAction= ko.observable(Addressdata.zipcode_id);
        self.statesArray = ko.observableArray($.parseJSON(statesJson));
        self.citiesArray = ko.observableArray($.parseJSON(citiesJson));
        self.zipcodeArray = ko.observableArray($.parseJSON(zipcodeJson));

        self.selectedStateAction.subscribe(function(newStateValue) {

            self.state_id = newStateValue;
            self.selectedCityAction = undefined;
            self.citiesArray = ko.observableArray();

            $.ajax({
                url: '/profile/getcities?mode=edit&state_id='+self.state_id,
                type: 'get',
                dataType: 'html',
                data: {},
                success: function(data) {
                    self.citiesArray = ko.observableArray($.parseJSON(data));
                }
            })
        });
}

var edit_address_form = document.getElementById("edit-address-form");
        ko.applyBindings( new EditUserAddressModel(resp1[0], resp2[0], resp3[0], Addressdata), edit_address_form);
```

**TPL code:**

```
<select class="form-control custom-form-control" data_from="edit_city" data-bind="options: $root.statesArray, optionsText: 'state_name', optionsValue: 'state_id', value: selectedStateAction, optionsCaption: 'Select State'"></select>
    <select class="form-control custom-form-control" data_from="edit_zip" id="edit_city" data-bind="options: citiesArray, optionsText: 'city_name', optionsValue: 'city_id', value: selectedCityAction, optionsCaption: 'Select City'"></select>
    <select class="form-control custom-form-control select_zip" id="edit_zip" data-bind="options: $root.zipcodeArray, optionsText: 'zip', optionsValue: 'zipcode_id', value: selectedZipAction, optionsCaption: 'Select Zip'"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
self.citiesArray = ko.observableArray($.parseJSON(data));
```

You replace your old `observableArray` reference, which was linked to other parts of your code and UI, by a new one.

You need to set an `observableArray` by calling it with a new value:

```
self.citiesArray($.parseJSON(data));
```